# wix installer "could not access network location"

Tags: wix

I get the error "could not access network location \Common" when running the installer.

Any ideas will be much appreciated.

```
<Property Id="BINDIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id='BinDirReg' Type='raw' Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\xxx' Name='AppDir' Win64='no'/>
</Property>
<Property Id="DATADIR">
  <RegistrySearch Id='DataDirReg' Type='raw' Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\xxx' Name='DataDir' Win64='no'/>
</Property>
<Property Id="WIXUI_INSTALLDIR" Value="INSTALLFOLDER" />
<UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
<SetDirectory Id="TESTBINFOLDER" Value="[BINDIR]\a\b\c" />
<SetDirectory Id="TESTDATAFOLDER" Value="[DATADIR]\a\b\c" />
<SetDirectory Id="TESTCOMMONDATAFOLDER" Value="[DATADIR]\Common" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the DATADIR property is empty so the value of TESTCOMMONDATAFOLDER is "\Common"

You really shouldn't be trying to define your Directory structure this way since on your very first install you'll try to set the TESTCOMMONDATAFOLDER to [DATADIR]\Common but there's no way your registry key exists in the registry.

You should define your Directory Structure as a default baseline. THere are several well-definied [System Folder Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx) for msis that you can use to define your default directory structure.

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="CompanyName">                
            <Directory Id="BIN" Name="_bin" />                    
            <Directory Id="DataDir" Name="Data" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="AppDataFolder" >
       <Directory Id="ProductName" />
    </Directory>
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="ProductName"/>
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Define your default structure this way. If you let the user set a custom install location, you can use a registry search to set the property for the directory and everything else will update nicely. for example,

```
<Property Id="INSTALLDIR">
    <RegistrySearch
            Id="InstallDirRegSearch"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\ProductName"
            Name="Path"
            Type="raw"/>
 </Property>
```

And this will set the INSTALLDIR to the custom location and all the BIN and DataDir folders will get updated with the new INSTALLDIR location. You can do a similar registry search to set directory locations for all other Directories. The plus side of doing it this way is that if these registry locations do not exist, you'll still use the default defined structure for your installation.